# Calculate the sum of this alternating sequence

Tags: calculus

I really don't understand how to calculate the sum for an alternating sequence... the sequence is:

$3 - \frac{9}{4}+\frac{27}{16}-\frac{81}{64}+...= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{3^{n+1}}{2^{2n}}$

Am I supposed to use $a_{2n}\le b\le a_{2n+1}$?

Comment: The terms are in geometric progression. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Just edited my post

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as $$3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

If the first term is called $a$ and the common ratio is called $r,$ with $|r| < 1,$ then the infinite sum is
$$  \frac{a}{1-r} $$

These are the letters I used in high school. The first term is $a=3.$ the common ratio is $r = - \frac{3}{4}.$ The infinite sum is
$$ \frac{3}{1 - \frac{-3}{4}} = \frac{3}{1 + \frac{3}{4}} =  \frac{3}{ \left( \frac{7}{4} \right)} = \frac{12}{7}$$

Comment: Is it $\frac{a}{1-r}$ or $\frac{a(r)}{1-r}$ ?

Comment: @BrynBurns what I put is correct. Your first term is $a=3,$ common ratio $r = \frac{-3}{4},$ so the infinite sum is $\frac{12}{7}$